# Static variable filled, later suddenly emptied?

Tags: php, static, static-variables

I've got a problem where I set a static variable (which I only access in the class it is defined in), but next time a method in that same class (all methods are static btw), it is suddenly null. I've checked, and there is no method accessing this variable. Is there something I'm missing?

```
class Foo {
    private static $var;

    public static function setTest($a) {
         self::$var = $a;
    }

    public static function getTest() {
         return self::$var;
    }
}
```

-----Edit-----
This is the actual class I'm working on:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Class Cache
 */
class Cache
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private static $cachedir;
    private static $checked = true;
    /**
     * @param $file_contents
     * @param string $class
     */
    public static function add($file_contents, $class = "", $method = "")
    {
        if (empty($class)) {
            $trace = debug_backtrace();
            if (!empty($trace[1])) {
                $class = $trace[1]["class"];
                $method = $trace[1]["function"];
            }
        }
        $cachedir = self::getDir();
        \Dir::make($cachedir . "/" . $class);
        \File::put($cachedir . "/" . $class, $method . ".cache", base64_encode(serialize($file_contents)));
    }
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getDir()
    {
        $cachedir = self::$cachedir;
        if (empty($cachedir)) {
            $cachedir = self::init();
        }
        return $cachedir;
    }
    /**
     * @param mixed $cachedir
     */
    public static function setDir($cachedir)
    {
        self::$cachedir = $cachedir;
    }
    /**
     *
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        if (empty($user)) {
            return false;
        }
        $cachedir = "cache/" . session_id() . "-" . $user["uid"];
        if (!\File::exists($cachedir . "/Cache/create_date.cache")) {
            self::setDir($cachedir);
            \Dir::make($cachedir);
            self::add(new \DateTime(), "Cache", "create_date");
            if (!\File::exists(APP_PATH . "/" . $cachedir . "/Env/environment.cache")) {
                self::add(\Env::getSettings(), "Env", "environment");
            }
        } elseif (self::$checked) {
//            $created_at = self::get("Cache", "create_date");
//            self::$checked = true;
//            dd($created_at);
        }
        return $cachedir;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $class
     * @param string $method
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get($class = "", $method = "")
    {
        if (empty($class)) {
            $trace = debug_backtrace();
            if (!empty($trace[1])) {
                $class = $trace[1]["class"];
                $method = $trace[1]["function"];
            }
        }
        $cachedir = self::getDir();
        if (!empty($cachedir)) {
            $path = APP_PATH . "/" . $cachedir . "/" . $class . "/" . $method . ".cache";
            if (\File::exists($path)) {
                $file = \File::get($path);
                return unserialize(base64_decode($file));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you invoked the function and it got emptied?

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://3v4l.org/iR1d5

Comment: Updated question @SahilGulati

Comment: @ChristianKaal i have checked it is working fine., Can you share how are invoking `setDir` and `getDir` basic test is here https://eval.in/809631

Comment: @SahilGulati I use Cache::init() once, later I use the get and add methods to get or add data to the cache. When the getDir is called, the dir variable is null and init gets called again.